# Ping ip address and save result to txt file.

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, ping

I am trying to open a list of ip address and ping them and then save the responce to a TXT file. The ping loops through and runs with out a problem and reports correctly but i can get it to save the results to a text file.

```
@echo off

SET LOGFILE=MyLogFile.log
call :Logit >> %LOGFILE% 
exit /b 0

for /f "delims=" %%a in ( ' type "C:\Users\kelly\Desktop\Ping\computerlist.txt" ' ) do ping -n 1 %%a >nul && (echo %%a ok >> %LOGFILE% ) || (echo %%a failed to respond >> %LOGFILE% ) 
pause
```

Comment: Is this an excerpt from your batch file? I don't see a label for Logit, just a call statement.

Comment: @sippybear no this is my whole scrip. I probably missed something I dont normally build bat files so i was googling and putting stuff together. Everything was good till to point of adding the results to the txt file.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
SET LOGFILE=C:\Temp\MyLogFile.log
SET PINGLIST=C:\Users\kelly\Desktop\Ping\computerlist.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%PINGLIST%) DO ping -n 1 %%a > nul && (echo %%a is ok >> %LOGFILE%) || (echo %%a is unreachable! >> %LOGFILE%)
```

Just make sure your computer list only has one hostname on each line.

Input (computerlist.txt)

```
gooobler
google.com
msn.com
localhost
```

Output (MyLogFile.log)

```
gooobler is unreachable! 
google.com is ok 
msn.com is unreachable! 
localhost is ok
```

Comment: Got it to work i had to run it as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Where you have 
`do ping -n 1 %%a >nul`

That is taking the ping output and throwing it away.

I think you want

`do ping -n 1 %%a >%LOGFILE%`

Also, you're calling a nonexistent region/subroutin (Logit)

```
@echo off

SET LOGFILE=MyLogFile.log
call :Logit >> %LOGFILE% 
exit /b 0

:Logit
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( ' type "C:\Users\kelly\Desktop\Ping\computerlist.txt" ' ) do ping -n 1 %%a >nul && (echo %%a ok >> %LOGFILE% ) || (echo %%a failed to respond >> %LOGFILE% ) 
pause
```

(untested)

~~Edit based on OP's comment and now having tested~~

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET LOGFILE=logFile.txt
SET TEMP_FILE=temp.txt
SET PINGLIST=comps.txt


REM contatenate log file
echo. > %LOGFILE%

for /f "delims=" %%a in (%PINGLIST%) do (
    REM do ping and store response - using a temp file because we care about the response more than once.
    ping -n 1 %%a > %TEMP_FILE%

    REM append response to log file
    type %TEMP_FILE% >> %LOGFILE%

    REM from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8531199
    REM check if ping determined the host is unreachable by searching the output
    findstr /c:"Destination host unreachable" /c:"could not find host" %TEMP_FILE% > NUL

    REM if the errorlevel is at least 1 (unsuccessful at finding string)
    if errorlevel 1 (
        REM then must have reached host
        echo %%a is ok >> %LOGFILE%
    ) ELSE (
        REM else, we found the string that sais we cannot reach the host
        echo %%a is UNREACHABLE^! >> %LOGFILE%
    )
    REM cleanup
    del %TEMP_FILE%
)
exit /b
```

Comment: So i now have this.

`@echo off
SET LOGFILE=C:\Users\kelly\Desktop\Ping\MyLogFile.log
SET PINGLIST=C:\Users\kelly\Desktop\Ping\computerlist.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%PINGLIST%) do ping -n 1 %%a > %LOGFILE% && (echo %%a is ok >> %LOGFILE%) || (echo %%a is unreachable! >> %LOGFILE%)

`
It works however it only writes to the first line and if two fail then it only shows the last one to be ran. I want to to show if it failed of if it was successful on all of them.

Comment: Ummm, I think that you want to make the `ping -n 1 %%a > %LOGFILE%` an append instead (`ping -n 1 %%a >> %LOGFILE%`) but I don't think this solves all your issues.

Because ping returns 0 (considers it a success as long as it gets any response even from your dns saying the destination is unreachable).

Comment: @Kelly I updated my post. You'll need to tweak the file paths to what you want to use, but I think it will work for you. (If you may have spaces in the paths, you'll also need to put quotes around the variables when they are used).

Answer (score 0):

I had slightly different requirements, so what I ended up with is below, I wanted a program to loop endlessly.

I wanted a file that **only** shows the non responsive pings and when they occured

And I wanted some sign that the CMD window hadn't stalled

So I added the time, an `errorlist.txt` and did a bit of fiddling here and there to try and make it work

I shall be installing it on two PCs, so that if the network error is on one of the PCs the other one can `snitch` on it.

And by pinging every device on their network from each PC and a couple of internet IP addresses it should make it **much** easier to home in on the intermittent problem, and if its a local or hardware issue to identify the culprit

```
@ECHO OFF

CD C:\PingTest


SET LOGFILE=logFile.txt

SET TEMP_FILE=temp.txt

SET PINGLIST=comps.txt

SET ERRORLIST=ErrorList.txt

echo. > %LOGFILE%
echo. > %ERRORLIST%

:START

cls

echo Pingtest Running

Time /T

REM Change the number after /t to pause for X seconds between loops. IE, /t 10 > NUL pauses for 10 seconds before running again

timeout /t 5 > NUL


Time /T >> %LOGFILE%
@ECHO OFF

echo. " " >> %LOGFILE%

REM contatenate log file
echo. > %LOGFILE%

REM contatenate log file



for /f "delims=" %%a in (%PINGLIST%) do (
    REM do ping and store response - using a temp file because we care about the response more than once.
    ping -n 1 %%a > %TEMP_FILE%

    REM append response to log file
    type %TEMP_FILE% >> %LOGFILE%

    REM from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8531199
    REM check if ping determined the host is unreachable by searching the output
    findstr /c:"Destination host unreachable" /c:"could not find host" %TEMP_FILE% > NUL

    REM if the errorlevel is at least 1 (unsuccessful at finding string)
    if errorlevel 1 (
        REM then must have reached host
        echo %%a is ok >> %LOGFILE%
    ) ELSE (
        REM else, we found the string that sais we cannot reach the host
    Time /T >> %ERRORLIST%
        echo %%a is UNREACHABLE^! >> %ERRORLIST%
    )
    REM cleanup
    del %TEMP_FILE%
)

Goto :START
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).